# Executing network commands android

Tags: java, android, linux

How can I execute network commands on android like

```
ifconfig - ping etc
```

I used

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ifconfig");
```

But the output was only the process ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ifconfig won't give you anything itself. you need to use `netcfg` or `ifconfig eth0`

```
$ /system/bin/ifconfig
/system/bin/ifconfig
$ netcfg
netcfg
lo       UP    127.0.0.1       255.0.0.0       0x00000049
dummy0   DOWN  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0x00000082
rmnet0   DOWN  25.116.182.253  255.255.255.252 0x00000000
rmnet1   DOWN  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0x00000000
rmnet2   DOWN  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0x00000000
rmnet3   DOWN  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0x00000000
rmnet4   DOWN  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0x00000000
rmnet5   DOWN  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0x00000000
rmnet6   DOWN  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0x00000000
rmnet7   DOWN  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0x00000000
usb0     DOWN  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0x00001002
sit0     DOWN  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0x00000080
ip6tnl0  DOWN  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0x00000080
gannet0  DOWN  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0x00001082
eth0     UP    192.168.1.141   255.255.255.0   0x00001043
$ ifconfig lo
ifconfig lo
lo: ip 127.0.0.1 mask 255.0.0.0 flags [up loopback running]
$ ifconfig eth0
ifconfig eth0
eth0: ip 192.168.1.141 mask 255.255.255.0 flags [up broadcast running multicast]
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `getOutputStream()` method of the `process` object instance. Any output created by the process will be readable on the output stream returned by that method.

Comment: I am doing this but still no output for the ifconfig

Comment: Are you checking the error stream, as well? Perhaps your process doesn't have permission to execute ifconfig.